Understanding the derivation of the expression
in my research work related to wireless communication, I have the following expression:
$$\tag{1}
r_1 = \sqrt{P}H_1H_2(\textbf{h}_2^T\Phi \textbf{h}_1)s+\sqrt{P}H_0h_0s+w$$
where,
$r_1$ is received signal, $H_1, H_2$ are constants, $\textbf{h}_1, \textbf{h}_2$ are $N \times 1$ Rayleigh random vectors,$\Phi$ is $N \times N$ diagonal Phase-shift matrix such that  $\Phi \triangleq diag\{\phi\} \text{with}$ $\phi = [e^{j\phi_1}, e^{j\phi_2},...,e^{j\phi_N}]^T$ and $\phi_n \in [0, 2\pi]$.
$h_0$ is a Rayleigh random variable, $w$ is additive white Gaussian noise with zero mean and variance $N_0$, $s$ is the transmitted signal such that $E\{|s|^2\} = 1$.
The optimal Phase-shift matrix $\Phi$ maximizing the received signal variance to noise variance ratio (SNR) is given by
$\phi_n = \angle \frac{h_0}{h_{2,n}h_{1,n}}$, where $\angle x$ is phase of complex number $x$ and $h_{1,n}, h_{2,n}$ are $n^{th}$ element of $\textbf{h}_1, \textbf{h}_2$ respectively.
The ratio of SNR for above expression (1) is given as
$$\tag{2}
\gamma_{\text{max}} = \frac{{P}|H_1|^2|H_2|^2}{N_w}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N|h_2,n||h_1,n|+|H||h_0|\right)^2
$$
where $H = \frac{H_0}{|H_1||H_2|}$
My query is how equation (2) is obtained from (1).
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.
